# Enviar valores de variables a un servidor externo

Tags: php

Hola que tal tengo la siguiente duda, obtengo los datos capturados por metodo POST

```
$classCode = $_POST["classCode"];
$estimate    = $_POST["estimate"];
$pdateTime    = $_POST["pdateTime"]; 
$pdateTime2    = $_POST["pdateTime2"]; 
$pickup_loc    = $_POST["pickup_loc"]; 
$pickup_time = $_POST["pickup_time"]; 
$rate_id    = $_POST["rate_id"];
$rdateTime    = $_POST["rdateTime"]; 
$rdateTime2    = $_POST["rdateTime2"]; 
$return_loc    = $_POST["return_loc"]; 
$return_time = $_POST["return_time"]; 
$tarifabase    = $_POST["tarifabase"];
```

Como hago para que ya que la variable esta inicializada con el dato capturado, ya sea juntarlo o uno por uno enviar los datos ingresados a un servidor externo.

Dispongo de un VPS donde se estarian recibiendo estos datos para procesarlos

Comment: Lo primero que necesitas es tener un script en ese servidor para recibir los datos, dependiendo de cómo lo hagas, puedes enviarlos con [cURL](https://voragine.net/weblogs/como-hacer-una-peticion-post-a-un-servidor-usando-curl-en-un-script-php)

Comment: Hola si, ya tengo contemplado el php en el servidor receptor de estos datos, pero no se utilizar curl, investigare, pero no hay una forma mas sencilla ?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer. Realmente `$_POST` es un array en sí mismo, si quieres simplificar, puedes enviar directamente `$_POST` sin más, y diseccionarlo allí donde lo recibes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la variable `$_POST` y enviarla al servidor externo mediante una petición HTTP con cURL:

```
// Inicializa cURL
ch = curl_init();

// Establece la URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://servidor-externo/');

// Establece los campos a enviar
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));

// Ejecuta la petición
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

// Cierra cURL
curl_close ($ch);
```

En el servidor remoto te tocará leer las variables almacenadas en `$_POST`

También puedes establecer los campos uno a uno, de esta manera:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
    'clasCode'  => $classCode,
    'estimate'  => $estimate,
    'pdateTime' => $pdateTime
)));
```